# Counting the characters of all my posts

Tags: php, foreach, strlen

I have the following PHP code:

```
    foreach($posts as $post)
    {      
            echo $post->post_content;
            echo strlen($post->post_content);                      
    }
```

The `echo $post->post_content;` echos the content of all my posts (combined with the foreach).

The `echo strlen($post->post_content);` displays the characters of all my individual posts.

Problem: How can I let it count the characters of all my posts together? I don't need the characters of the first post, second post, etc. I need the characters of all posts together.

Comment: before the loop: `$count = 0;` and in the loop: `$count += strlen($post->post_content);`?

Comment: can't you just sum the lenghts of each post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it.

```
<?php
$total = 0;

foreach($posts as $post)
{
    $total += strlen($post->post_content);
}

echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the length of all post

```
$len = 0;
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->post_content;
    $len = $len+strlen($post->post_content);
}
echo $len;
```